# How to recognize and verify a simple sequence of events with drools fusion

Tags: drools, complex-event-processing, drools-fusion

I'm unable to find the best way (the drools fusion way actually) to count "A" events between "B" events (STREAM mode). An example of sequence could be:

```
B A A A B A A B A...
```

A use case could be

> verify a sequence validity i.e there is always 3 "A" events between
>   each "B" event

I don't know if the "window over" concept is appropriate in such a situation. Thanks for your help, I still have some difficulties to think in CEP way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two Drools versions cause two different behaviors (same Unit Test). So I think my misunderstood comes from a bug in "windows" behavior. I can't be more specific this time.